# Where can I find history of Pune or `Peshwa's`?

Tags: india, political-history, british-empire, indian

Where can I find the history of pune or [`Peshwa's`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peshwa)?

Links on Wikipedia are not enough, Please explain or paste link in answers.

To be more descriptive :
 1. Who were `peshwas` ?
 2. When did they exist?
 3. How did they fall, if they fell?
 4. How many years did they rule?
 5. What was relation of British-empire and Peshwas?
 6. How was this community formed?
 7. Significance
    i. Political Significance

Please help me understand this.

Comment: Please provide the links from wikipedia so we can see what it is you don't understand.  History is about sources; omitting the sources is like riding a bicycle without wheels or a seat.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peshwa) is link `@Mark` Here is a lot of description given you might think that you have all the answers to the above questions asked but there are more stories present outside this and there is no reference to those things here, [Like this](http://www.historyfiles.co.uk/KingListsFarEast/IndiaMarathasPeshwas.htm), I just found out  after asking this question. `@Killing Time`Thanks for the edit.

Comment: If they don't answer your question, you need to explain to us why that is. What else do you want to know, why it might be incomplete, etc. And you need to be focused on a particular aspect.

Comment: Look at History of Marattha  - By James Grant Duff (3 volumes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my attempt at briefly answering the questions.

1. It was a generic position similar to a Prime Minister, but mainly it is used to rulers of Maratha Empire which was seated at Pune, under the rule of Balaji Vishwanath and his successors until Bajirao II.
2. The title existed from the start of Maratha Empire, but again, the title Peshwa is mainly used for the period from Balaji Vishwanath, i.e. 1713 - 1818.
3. "Peshwai", as it's called, ended in 1818, when British annexed the region.
4. A quick math tells me 1818-1713+1 = 106 years, if Peshwa is taken in the sense I described above.
5. It was a complicated thing, as the history of the relations spanned across a century, and deserves a question of its own (and even that would be *too broad* for this site). Certainly it wasn't all friendly, especially since British annexed it in the end.
6. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balaji_Vishwanath#Ascent_to_Peshwa) link explains how Balaji Vishwanath got the title of a Peshwa.
7. What do you mean significance? Significance in which aspect? Even this is too broad to answer.
   7.1. Same as above.